# How do i capture Boostrap multiselect dropdown options in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I got this Bootstrap Multiselect Dropdown piece and it displayed fine in HTML. But my problem is how do i capture the selected options in PHP

Here's the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiselect</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
                var message = "";
                selected.each(function () {
                    message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
                });
                alert(message);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <form>
                <select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple" name="fruits">
                    <option value="1">Lemon</option>
                    <option value="2">Apple</option>
                    <option value="3">Banana</option>
                    <option value="4">Guava</option>
                    <option value="5">Orange</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="create_class">Create</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

Then to capture options in PHP, i did

```
if (array_key_exists(create_fruits, $_POST)) {
    echo $_POST['fruits'];
}
```

But nothing happened. please, what do i do?

Comment: How are you calling the PHP?

Comment: Where are you defining `create_fruits` in your `array_key_exists`?  I noticed that this isn't being parsed as a string to search so PHP would be treating it like a defined variable.  If it doesn't exist then `array_key_exists` comes back as `false` and nothing would be output.

Comment: Oh sorry, the button is be create_class and not create_fruits. But nothing happened still.

Comment: In your dropdown menu the 'name' property should have been defined as an array to accept multiple choices so instead of ``"fruits"`` it should be ``name="fruits[]"`` (This does not affect how you use it in your php code so it's still ``$_POST['fruits']`` or whatever you're using for that matter)

Comment: ok, i made the correction to name="fruits[]" and somehow, it worked. Thanks